# Is the "Renaissance Weekend" for real?

Tags: scams, conferences

I got an unsolicited invitation to the "Renaissance Weekend" which bills itself as sort of an idea conference for "thought leaders". Supposedly it is exclusive and limited to influential people. However, I am not an especially influential person. Not only that, the invitation was mailed to me by a pre-sorted, mass mailing. The included invitation card was fancy, but does not address me by name and appears to be mass printed.

I read a few "news" articles about it, but I got the sense they could have been planted by the people who run the conference and are just PR jobs.

Is this thing for real, or is it just a scam to get people to pay $1000 for wine and cheese?

Comment: "Renaissance Weekend" seems legitimate. But it doesn't mean that the invitation you got is related to it, or that being legitimate plus wine and cheese is worth 1000$. Did they provide a link / mail for registration?

Comment: Maybe upload the invite here to help understanding what the weekend is about.

Comment: More likely a way to sell overpriced product.

Comment: It's a total scam, forget it.

Comment: Save your money....[although dated](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=139980) it's essentially people paying big bucks to be in the presence of other people who are paid big bucks to show up

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the legitimacy of some event, not about travel.

Answer (score 3):

[Renaissance Weekend](https://www.renaissanceweekend.org/home.htm) bills itself as

> [N]on-partisan retreats created to build bridges among innovative leaders from diverse fields.

Founded in 1981, it is awash in 80's corporate-speak buzz words: pre-eminent, thought-leaders, trend-setters, change-makers, ground breaking, impactful, enduring.... It boasts such participants as

> Nobel laureates, Pulitzer Prize-winners, venture capitalists, social entrepeneurs & CEOs, leading innovators of Silicon Valley, Hollywood, Wall Street & Main Street, astronauts & Olympians, Republicans, Democrats & Independents.

Is the invite legit? Could be. Only after registering and paying fees will you know [whether you're among](https://www.renaissanceweekend.org/commonquestions/commonquestions.htm#q25) the

> [V]ery limited number of others expressing interest [who] may be included, based on their potential contribution to the expertise, depth, breadth, and diversity of perspectives at each Weekend.